# How to replace element without childs in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to replace an element but leave the child nodes intact.

```
var $row = $j('td[id^=someId]').parent();

$row.replaceWith('<tr class="headerRow">' + $row.html() + '</tr>');

$row.children().each(function () {
    $j(this).replaceWith('<th class="headerRow">' + $j(this).html() + '</th>');
});
```

The first replaceWith works - the second doesn't. Any ideas why?

Comment: You've a typo in the opening tag `th` should be `tr` instead `'<th class="headerRow">' + $j(this).html() + '</tr>'`

Comment: Copy & paste be damned! Thanks for noticing. Sadly it still doesn't work.

Comment: In the first case, you're placing the row and in the second replacing a column, is that what you want ? and could you please show us the content of `$row` ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. While the row replace works, the column replace doesn't happen at all.

Comment: I added the content of `$row` to the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example isn't working because you're replacing the `$row` on the page with a new element. Because `$row` is no longer on the page, any changes you make to it will not be reflected. You'd have to re-fetch that new element .

If you replaced the cells *before* the row, it should work just fine:

```js
var $row = $("tr").first();

$row
  .children()                                                      //Get children
  .replaceWith(function() {                                        //Replace them
    return '<th class="headerRow">' + $(this).html() + '</th>';
  })
  .end()                                                           //Refer to the original $row
  .replaceWith('<tr class="headerRow">' + $row.html() + '</tr>');  //Replace it
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="notHeaderRow">
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Side note: I've replaced your `.each` with a `replaceWith` *function*. I'd imagine it would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: So - first of all, I really like your example. It's a nifty solution to the problem and I really like it. For some reason it leaves the original `<td/>` though. Also I'm really confused why my example works for you as it clearly doesn't for me. I'll check my example again. Thanks!

Comment: @Semmel Unfortunately my initial thought wouldn't work properly, as `unwrap` requires children elements (which the `<td>` elements don't have), so I've used `replaceWith` instead. I've made it a function so that you can still avoid using an `each()` loop though. Additionally, I've modified my answer to explain why your example above didn't work. Hopefully this clears everything up!

Comment: The `<td/>` is now correct but instead the `<tr/>` is wrapped twice. :D Also thanks for the explanation - I will test my original solution implementing your feedback.

Comment: @Semmel I've removed my alternative method for now, as unfortunately I don't have enough time to fix it. That said, I've left the correction to your version, and replaced your `.each`. Sorry about that!

Comment: It is exactly as you said - once you process the child nodes first and the parent afterwards it works like a charm. So the problem was just in the order of execution.